# Length specified in network packet payload did not match number of bytes read; the connection has been closed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am having one of our SQL server 2005 servers coming out, from time to time with the following message:

SQL Server Alert System: 'Severity 20 - Fatal error in current Process' occurred on \myserver

Length specified in network packet payload did not match number of bytes read; the connection has been closed.

[image]

I have had a look at the sql log but could not find anything related to this.

On google I could only find [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/04446c40-0623-4528-bbbd-f05f9578e5a0/error-17836-severity-20-state-1?forum=sqldatabaseengine) where I could read the following info:

Perform a nslookup of the CLIENT IP Address that is listed in the error message and find out what computer it is that is connecting.  Then you need to check that machine and determine what specifically is connecting to the SQL Server.  You might get more infromation from doing a SQL Trace for the Errors and Warnings Event Class and have the ClientProcessID column in the trace data.  When the error spikes, you might get the PID for the process that is connecting from that 10.26.32.96 machine, and then you can find that process in Task Manager on that machine by adding the PID to the data displayed (View -> Select Columns).

this happened a few days ago.
what can I put in place on myServer so that the next time this error happens I have more details in order to find out what caused it?

when I run

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_io_cluster_shared_drives
```

it returns nothing, so it is not a clustered server

I use solarwinds to monitor HTTP connections and apparently there is something wrong on the reporting services as you can see on the picture below.

[image]

Further investigation shows that it is a LOGON issue, as you can see on the picture below, from the sql error logs.

[image]

But the question remains, how can I tackle this one? any suggestions?

Comment: faulty network card?

Comment: @MitchWheat Just checked and apparently not. I have just edited the question to add some more info.